# what sould be done to have same layout for diffrent android applications?

Tags: android

hiii everybody,

I have an important question regarding android. I build an application in android,which uses some layout.Supoose I tested on a real android device.
My question is:
**Whether the layout and whole look and feel will be same when i run in different android device?
If not, what i have to do to ensure same layout and same look ans feel ie. layout must not distort while running in other android device ?**

Answer (score 2):

Check [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) post, it has lots of information about supporting multiple screens when developing for Android. Hope this helps.